# How to select a radio button in an Access application programmatically from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, automation, radio-button

I need to

1. Open an Access Application by clicking on a button in Excel.
2. Select a radio button.
3. Click on Ok button

I am able to do the first step. But I am not able to select the radio button. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: You are better off calling the vba code that correspond to the radio button. You do not need to deal with the GUI elements to get things done.

Comment: Thank you Tarik for your reply. But there is no method or vba code associated with the radio button. So I am not able to call the vba code directly.